# Referencing external images in postscript using Xerox Freeflow server

Tags: image, variables, postscript

I want to be able to reference an image in a postscript file from a separate file location on my Xerox FreefLow print server rather than embed it into the postscript directly. This is to allow for print files that are very variable and have over a hundred variable images to choose from. I have tried using 'run exec' or 'GetTiff' Commands without success.  Any advice on using VIPP postscript commands would be appreciated - postscript output is generated from PreS and PDF output is not an option.

Sample postscript I have tried

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
/Times-Bold findfont
20 Scalefont
setfont
200 450 moveto
(The Document Company Bryan) show
gsave
initgraphics
(/opt/XRXnps/resources/bf/czrdrf.ps.p000000001.ps) run exec)
grestore
showpagetext
```

Comment: Can you edit to add more details about what you've tried? How did you try using those commands? Code?

Comment: Ok. And the printer (or at least the Postscript interpreter) has access to this file-system? Or do you maybe need to *download* the data into the printer first?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about the Xerox Freeflow server, but I can offer some critique of your postscript code.

First, `initgraphics` should never be used in a document program. The graphics should already be initialized to the default settings by default, and if not, maybe it's because the code has been embedded into an altered context. Here, the only things altered are the current font (default is an invalid font), and defined the current point (default is undefined). Unless the embedded program *depends* upon these two elements of the graphics state to be undefined, there's no need to mess with resetting the state.

`run` *runs* the program in the named file. `exec` would only be needed if the result of the program file were a partially-evaluated procedure of some kind. I doubt this is the case. So my *guess* is that `exec` is causing a stackunderflow error and aborting the program. There should be some way to configure the server to report postscript errors back to you. Or error reports may be in a log file.

`showpagetext` is not a standard ps operator. `showpage` is.

---

I'd suggest you try with a simpler ps program, rather than the image program. First, we need to be sure that the file is accessible to the interpreter. So, we need to know if the error in the above program was actually *stackunderflow* as I suspect, or *invalidfilename* or *invalidfileaccess* or *ioerror* or something else.

If any or all of these efforts fail, there is an older postscript technique that you might consider. If the interpreter can create and write files, you can *download* the image by writing a program which writes the image program to disk. If that works, reading from the file later should also work.